# Set a condition for i = 0 in For Loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I find myself consistently having to set a condition for i = 0 in my For Loops and am wondering if there's a more efficient way to go about writing the for loop. For example:

```
For i = 0 to UBound(arr)
    If i = 0 then
        ws.range("A1") = arr(i)
        else
            ws.range("A1") = ws.range("A1") & ", " & arr(i)
    End If
Next i
```

Basically I'm wondering if this is the most efficient way to do this or if there's something I'm missing that would make this much more efficient.

Comment: What about Join?

Comment: Too many cell read/write steps (one read and write in each iteration) - those are what kill your performance in Excel VBA `ws.Range("A1").Value = join(arr, ", ")`

Comment: Why not ' For i=1 to Ubound(arr)' then you won't have to write A1 twice.

Answer (score 1):

`Join()` is probably your best bet here, but you can simplify the type of loop you posted so there's only one cell write:

```vb
Dim i As Long, sep As String, v As String

For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    v = v & sep & arr(i)
    sep = ", " 'assign after first value
Next i
ws.Range("A1").Value = v
```

Comment: Clever idea to benefit from eventual assignment :+)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with a loop you could also do it like that

```
Dim s As String
For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        s = s & arr(i) & ","
Next i
ws.Range("A1").Value = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
```

Comment: To avoid arithmetics you could also reduce the iterations by 1 to only `For i = 0  To Ubound(arr) - 1` and eventually assign `ws.Range("A1").Value = s & arr(i)` outside the loop. @Storax